# Merge Sort: Why are there no remaining elements in the right part?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

Using code from [this link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsMergesort/article.html), the `merge` function does not have a `while` loop for the remaining `j` elements from the right part of the temp (`helper`) array into the original (`numbers`) array.

It still works fine. I was wondering if someone could help explain why `j` always reaches `high` (because of which there are no remaining elements on the right part of the `helper` array which needs to be simply copied into the `numbers` array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `merge(low, middle, high)` starts from copying the elements of `numbers` to the `helper` array.

That is why `numbers` array already has the elements and there is no point to copy them back from the `helper`.

Comment: Oh! So is it like this: Since `j` is pointing to the latter half of the array, we need not copy back the remaining sorted elements from indices `j` to `high` because they are already sorted by the previous recursion calls to `merge` and already stored within the `numbers` array. Did I get it right? Please do let me know.

Comment: Good explanation.. Even I had the same doubt !!